# What would be the easiest way to add a database to html file?

Tags: python, html, django, database, server-side

So I have made a project website with a couple html files, css and some javascript. I was thinking that I would add a login functionality and some other things like that. So I set off to find out what would be good for it. Now its is hard for me because I can't decide which one to use. I saw Django on python but I had to make a whole new project for it and I have to start from scratch. I was just thinking I would add a database to this site using something. I am just doing some lightweight things. What should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are not going to use python for this with Django, you could use PHP and MySQL. I do it all the time for small sites. Basically just go to your hosting panel and create a new DB and then use php to create a connection script and then go from there as far as adding and using the database. All web hosts support this feature that I know of. If you go with Django though, you can simply add the sqllite3 DB or use something like MongoDB or any other DB out there really. Please look up the exact documentation for whichever route you choose.

Comment: ok thank you for the answer!